# hide div on random click using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a search icon, on click it its open search bar and hide the menu, but now i want to make search div close when random click on page. i tried to make it but i failed, please help:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a#top-search').click(function(){
            $('#searchform').toggleClass('block');
            $('.main-nav').toggleClass('none');
        });
        if ($('#searchform').hasClass('block')){
            $(body).click(function(){
              $('#searchform').addClass('none');    
            }); 
        };
    });
</script>
```

Comment: i would change the check around so on body click then check if search form has class. Just noticed someone already said this. If you provide code we could have a proper look ourselves. Even better, add  JSFIDDLE :)

Comment: <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("body").click(function(){
            if($('#searchform').hasClass('block')){
               $('#searchform').addClass('none');  
               $('.main-nav').addClass('block'); 
            }; 
        });
     });
 </script>
 
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('a#top-search').click(function(){
    $('#searchform').toggleClass('block');
    $('.main-nav').toggleClass('none');
    
   });
  });
 </script>

Answer (score 1):

Try to rewrite your code like this,

```
$("body").click(function(){
  if($('#searchform').hasClass('block')){
    $('#searchform').addClass('none');    
  }); 
});
```

Bind event to `body` and check your conditions inside of it.

Comment: it did not work even search icon click function stopped working

Comment: @VikasS Can you create a simple demo here? jsfiddle.net?